# Speeding up pandas calculations

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a long Dataframe, df, and a shorter Dataframe, df2. I have to make a calculation which is referring to each of the lines in the long Dataframe. Then I have to cut it and merge it with part of the second Dataframe. In the end, I have to assign the results.

```
res = []   
for iRow, row in df1.iterrows():
        df1 = df.assign(dtf=1 - abs((df1.time - row.time) / pd.Timedelta('2 hours')))
        df1 = df1[df1.dtf > 0]
        df2 = df2.loc[(df2.x == row.x) & (df2.y != 0)]
        df1 = df1.merge(df2)
        df1 = df1.assign(z=df1.dtf * df1.y)
        res.append((df1.y.sum(), df1.z.sum())
```

I clearly see that my CPU and memory are not very busy but I assume that parallelization would take more time than a direct calculation. The one method that I think could speed up the calculation is staying inside pandas rather than iteration via Python...

Is there any way to speed up the calculation?

Comment: Only a single core is being used. On a 4 core computer, that amounts to 25% CPU, This is in addition to the slow processing when you loop in Python. Give Julia a try. It's blazing fast.

Comment: To answer your question: Do away with Pandas in this case and use a combination of lists and dictionaries. You can use named tuples to hold rows.

Comment: @Tarik not sure that I am following you

Comment: Modern PCs have multiple cores (virtually multiple CPUs on a single chip). Python and in fact many other software packages are not designed to make use of all the cores of the CPU. As a result,bayou only use a portion of your computing capacity. As a simple test, write a simple loop that keeps incrementing a variable forever. Run it and see how much CPU is used.

Comment: @Tarik this I did follow. What you mean by "Do away with Pandas in this case and use a combination of lists and dictionaries. You can use named tuples to hold rows."?

Comment: Python is an interpreted language and is a couple of magnitudes slower than compiled languages such as C or FORTRAN, that represent the benchmark in terms of processing speed. Moreover, these languages allow for multiple threads to process data and perform calculations in parallel, thereby making use of all the CPU cores.

Comment: Well, instead of having a Pandas DataFrame, you can have a list of tuples. Each tuple represents one row. You can create dictionaries for fast lookup and get a better performance.

Comment: `df1 = df1[df1.dtf > 0]` You are creating a new DataFrame while you are looping over the rows of df1. That's correct but confusing. Creating a DataFrame in a loop is expensive. See if you can use loc instead. Oh, you are merging it. Nevermind. I think you need to rethink the whole algorithm.

Comment: @Tarik I am trying...That is the whole purpose of this post

Comment: Pandas DataFrames and the underlying numpy library are aimed at vectorized operations whereby you add, multiply and execute other operations on entire slices of rows/columns. The actual execution is done by the compiled C code these libraries have been developed with, taking full advantage of the processor. Once you find yourself looping in Python/Pandas, your are gone for slow execution. A way out of this is to use Virgin, but then you are in for quite a ride.